# QGIS 3.4 Geopackage Raster Handling and DB Manager

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, geopackage

I just discovered something about Geopackage rasters and QGIS 3.4:

- Exporting a img-Raster into a Geopackage works fine - also opening it
- Opening the this "geopackage raster" in ArcGIS Pro 2.3.3 does not work
- Exporting the same raster with ArcGIS Pro into the geopackage works and also opening this one in QGIS or ArcGIS Pro
- Having a look with the QGIS DB Manager on the geopackage with the raster was mysterious: It just showed the raster created by ArcGIS Pro in the geopackage, but not the rasters created by QGIS ?

Does someone know why the IMG-->GeoPackage raster does not work with ArcGIS Pro and is not shown in the QGIS DB Manager, whereas the ArcGIS Pro created rasterlayer in this geopackage works well and is shown in QGIS DB Manager ?

The difference seems to be the data_type-field (Screenshot 3).

[image: AG pro created raster layer visible in DB Manager]

[image: All 3 raster layers that are in the GPKG]

[image: View on the DB]

Comment: I opened a TIFF file with QGIS 3.4.1, saved with "Layer - Save as" into geopackage and I have no problems when I open this new .gpkg database with QGIS DB Manager. Data_type of the new layer is "tiles". How did you create the geopackage?

Comment: I found the reason for it:
Using an image (DEM - single band; IMG-format) and exporting it into a geopackage raster layer with QGIS creates a layer in the GPKG with the data_type "2d-gridded-coverage" - this saves the raster values (in the case of DEM the hight) as they are (single band). This type of raster-layer in the GPKG is not recognized by the DB Manager and ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3 (but it is well handled by QGIS). AG Pro creates with "Add raster to GPKG" a rendered image (no other option) which AG Pro "knows" and DB Manager too (but is not suitable for a single-band DEM because of rgb).

Comment: OK, then ArcGIS does not yet support the specific extension that is made for DEM data and alike http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/17-066r1/17-066r1.html.

Comment: Thx! I reported it to ESRI.

Answer (score 4):

ArcGIS pro (2.2.3) "Add raster to geopackage" only creates data_type "tiles" (rgb)-images (not suitable for DEM). QGIS-Eport to GPKG supports "tiles" (rgb-images) AND raw-data (2d-gridded-coverage) for DEM (http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/17-066r1/17-066r1.html). QGIS DB-Manager is also not aware of GPKG-rasters of the data_type 2d-gridded-coverage. Hopefully with future versions of AG Pro the support of rasters in geopackages improves (reported to ESRI) and QGIS-DB-Manager too.